# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting the following error when I try to send the message using the below sequence I don't know why I am getting this please help me and if you need more information please let me know (version of ESB is 4.8.1 )

### Trace

TID: [0] [ESB] [2021-12-03 09:38:01,437] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  access-control-allow-credentials:true,Alt-Svc:h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,Content-Type:application/json,permissionallowed:VEAD,vary:Origin,Via:1.1 google,x-content-type-options:nosniff,x-envoy-upstream-service-time:27,x-xss-protection:1; mode=block,<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soapenv:Body`DD_412`Status ReportRuntime ErrorNo Product returned Product Id 11111</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:578)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:256)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:185)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:349)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:74)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:44)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:160)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:74)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:44)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:135)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:498)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:233)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:65)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:440)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:254)
... 20 more

sequence for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="emt_Service_Fault_Handler">
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           source="boolean(get-property('EMT_ERROR_MSG'))"
           regex="^true$">
      <then>
         <header name="To" scope="default" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="default" action="remove"/>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" value="412" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <filter source="boolean(get-property('EMT_ERROR_CODE'))" regex="^true$">
            <then/>
            <else>
               <property name="EMT_ERROR_CODE" value="DD_412"/>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <Fault xmlns="">
                  <code>$1</code>
                  <type>Status Report</type>
                  <message>Runtime Error</message>
                  <description>$2</description>
               </Fault>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('EMT_ERROR_CODE')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('EMT_ERROR_MSG')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <header name="To" scope="default" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="default" action="remove"/>
         <property name="ERROR_CODE"
                   expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <Fault xmlns="">
                  <code>$1</code>
                  <type>Status Report</type>
                  <message>Runtime Error</message>
                  <description>$2</description>
               </Fault>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>
```

Comment: where do you use this sequence. Is this in the in sequence or the out sequence

Comment: @ShanakaPremarathna this is an out sequence